# Google sheets: Sum if with vlookup or match when there are multiple matches

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, sumifs

I have a lookup table that classifies the names of columns. For example, the column names are goat, mouse, and butterfly, and the classification table shows that these column names are mammal, mammal, insect, respectively. For each row, I need to sum all columns that belong to the 'mammal' class. See picture below (my firewall may not allow the picture, so I can try again at home).

[image: example]

What I currently have is just returning the first column match, instead of all columns that match 'mammal'.

=sumif($B$1:$F$1, vlookup("Mammal", $K$1:$L$5, 2,0),B2:F2)

One little curve ball is that this sheet is going to be dynamic. People will be adding animal columns and classifying them in the lookup table, and I don't want them to be editing the formula.

Answer (score 1):

How about this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:F1,N(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B$1:F$1,{L:L,K:K},2,0))="Mammal")))
```

then drag it down?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I think there is an extra end parentheses. Also, it should be SUMPRODUCT(B2:F2, n...). Thank you again!